# Firebase REST API: Delete sometimes fails

Tags: matlab, rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm currently building a web frontend for a Matlab program. I'm using webread/webwrite to interface with the Firebase realtime database (Though I'll be shifting to urlread2 soon for compatibility reasons). The Matlab end has to delete nodes from the database on a regular basis. I do this by using webwrite to send a POST request and putting "X-HTTP-Method-Override: DELETE" in the header. This works, but after a few deletes it stops working until data is either added to or removed from the database. It seems completely random, my teammate and I have been trying to find a pattern for a few days and we've found nothing.

Here is the relevant Matlab code:

```
modurl = strcat(url, modkey, '.json');
modurlstr = char(modurl);
webop = weboptions('KeyName', 'X-HTTP-Method-Override', 'KeyValue','DELETE');
webwrite(modurlstr, webop);
```

Where url is our database url and modkey is the key of the node we're trying to delete. There's no authentication because the database is set to public (Security is not an issue for us).

The database is organized pretty simply. The root node just has a bunch of children. We only delete a whole child (i.e. we don't ever try to delete the individual components of a child).

Are we doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We found out some of the keys had hyphens in them, which were getting translated to their ascii representation. The reason it seemed random was because the delete was only bugging out on the nodes which had a hyphen in their keys. When we switched them back everything worked fine.